# ggplot - modifying the legend in case when using color and alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following plot:

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = len, 
                   color = factor(dose),
                   fill = factor(dose),
                   alpha = supp,
                   group = interaction(factor(dose), supp))) + 
  geom_density()
```

[image]

First thing, the legend seems a bit wrong because it displays the same value of `alpha` for both values in `supp`. However, that's not so important.

I would like the legend to look like this (made in Paint):

[image]

Note that I used the empty box as a substitute for low alpha in this hand-drawn (mouse-drawn) image, and the filled box represents high alpha.

Does anyone have any idea on how to even approach this, or how would it be possible to code it?

I don't have strong feelings about the placement of the text parts in the legend. My central interest is to have this matrix of six colored boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where I make a plot for the legend and combine it in.

[image]

```
legend_plot <- ggplot(data.frame(dose = factor(c(0.5, 1, 2)),
                  supp = rep(c("OJ", "VC"), each = 3)), 
       aes(x = supp, y = forcats::fct_rev(dose), 
                        color = factor(dose),
                        fill = factor(dose),
                        alpha = supp,
                        group = interaction(factor(dose), supp))) + 
  geom_tile(linewidth = 1, height = 0.8, width = 0.8) + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none") +
  labs(y = "dose") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

library(patchwork)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = len, 
                        color = factor(dose),
                        fill = factor(dose),
                        alpha = supp,
                        group = interaction(factor(dose), supp))) + 
  geom_density() +
  guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none") +
  legend_plot +
  plot_layout(design = "
              1#
              12
              1#", widths = c(3,1))
```